# "Multiple filters matched." when using same address for multiple endpoints in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, service, endpoint

So, due to some organizational concerns, I've split up what was intially a single interface contract into two seperate ones. Now, I have only one class implementing both interfaces, and I want to make them all available as REST-services through WCF. 
The contracts are listed below:

1st:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface INotification
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    XElement GetInfo(string appID);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    void RegisterRID(string appID, string registrationID);
}
```

2nd:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPlanning
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    XElement PlanTrip(string toDestination, string fromDestination, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, string appID);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    XElement PlanTripDelayed(string toDestination, string fromDestination, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, string appID);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    XElement PlanTripLoc(string toDestination, string fromLat, string fromLong, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, string appID);
}
```

My app.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="RESTFriendly">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service name="TravelPlannerWebService.Domain.Entity.ETravelPlanner">
            <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="TravelPlannerWebService.Acquaintance.IPlanning" behaviorConfiguration="RESTFriendly" />
            <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="TravelPlannerWebService.Acquaintance.INotification" behaviorConfiguration="RESTFriendly" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:80" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Problem being, whenever I try to use two interfaces, I get an error. Through looking at my app_tracelog.svclog (I've removed debug code from app.config intentionally here), I can see that I get the following error:

Message: Multiple filters matched.

Stack Trace:

```
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcherTable.LookupInCache(Message message, Boolean&amp; addressMatched)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcherTable.Lookup(Message message, Boolean&amp; addressMatched)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.GetDatagramChannel(Message message, EndpointDispatcher&amp; endpoint, Boolean&amp; addressMatched)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.EnsureChannelAndEndpoint(RequestContext request)
           System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.TryRetrievingInstanceContext(RequestContext request)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContextCore(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContext(IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.WaitCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

I have no idea how to solve this. As far as I can see, from following guides, this is the correct way to use the same type for multiple endpoints. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the below and see if you still get an exception:

```
<service name="TravelPlannerWebService.Domain.Entity.ETravelPlanner">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="TravelPlannerWebService.Acquaintance.IPlanning" behaviorConfiguration="RESTFriendly" />
        <endpoint address="more" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="TravelPlannerWebService.Acquaintance.INotification" behaviorConfiguration="RESTFriendly" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:80" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
```

You cannot have 2 different endpoints listening on the same address. Hence, I have added the address attribute to distinguish them.

Your URLs might be as follows when hosted in IIS:

```
http://localhost/ApplicationVD/PlanTrip
http://localhost/ApplicationVD/PlanTripDelayed
http://localhost/ApplicationVD/PlanTripLoc
http://localhost/ApplicationVD/More/GetInfo
http://localhost/ApplicationVD/More/RegisterRID
```

Comment: Strange, since in the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395210.aspx they use identical adresses for two endpoints with seperate contracts?

Comment: If you look at the article they are using a ListenUri property whose value is set and that property lets you have different contracts listening on the same address.

Comment: Okay, just thought it wasn't needed, since the ListenUri has the same value for both. Will try that approach.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer here is that you need to remember the ABC of <strike>Indigo</strike> ... ahem ... WCF: Address, Binding, Contract.

The fact that your service's endpoints are implemented within the same physical class is irrelevant to your service's callers: To the outside world, your service is now exposed via two distinct service endpoints: IPlanning & INotification.

Modify your app.config file's endpoints to expose each service endpoint at its own address (relative to your service's base address):

```
<endpoint name ="TripPlanningEndpoint" 
    address="Planning" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service.IPlanning" 
    behaviorConfiguration="RESTFriendly" />

<endpoint name="TripNotificationsEndpoint" 
    address="Notifications" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service.INotification" 
    behaviorConfiguration="RESTFriendly" />
```

Oh ... and you don't need all the REST Friendly endpoint behavior stuff - webHttpBinding already supports httpGet by default. :)

Also, I strongly encourage you to enable service metadata (esp' while developing) as this allows you to use tools to generate the client-side proxy classes to allow you to quickly build (properly configured) client apps and tests.

To your service's app.config class, add the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
     ...
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceMetadataBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Also add an additional endpoint to expose your service's metadata:

```
<endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
```

Now you can add references to your client/test apps using "Add Service Reference":
[image: Multi-interface WCF Service - Add Reference Dialog]

HTH.

Comment: On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395210.aspx, they actually show that it is possible to have two endpoints, with seperate contracts, sharing the same address? Am I mistaken somehere?
I deliberately removed the service metadata, since testing of all methods has already been done in the former implementation with only one interface. The refactorization have been done due to architectural concerns (providing better overview.)